# A value of type 'User' can't be returned from the method '_userFromFirebaseUser'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:xchat/modal/user.dart' as UserModal;

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? UserModal.User(userId: user.uid):null;
  }
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User firebaseUser = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**I don't know I am getting a error like this-**

> A value of type 'User (where User is defined in
> f:\code\flutter\xchat\lib\modal\user.dart)' can't be returned from the
> method '_userFromFirebaseUser' because it has a return type of 'User
> (where User is defined in
> C:\Users\hossa\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.1.0\lib\src\user.dart)'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)
> user.dart(1, 7): User is defined in
> f:\code\flutter\xchat\lib\modal\user.dart user.dart(8, 7): User is
> defined in
> C:\Users\hossa\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.1.0\lib\src\user.dart

**Please help me to solve this error.
Thank You**

Comment: Users are conflicting. Change your own user class to some other name like `MyUser`

Comment: In that case. I'll post that as answer. Mark it as correct , if that helped .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are conflicting. Change your own user class to some other name like `MyUser`  or tell dart **explicitly** which `User` to use

Answer (score 0):

your _userFromFirebaseUser return type is your User class in model and you are returning firebaseuser

Try this

```
_userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
return user != null ? UserModal.User(userId: user.uid):null;
}

Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
try {
  UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  User firebaseUser = result.user;
  return await _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**All I need to change the class name User**

```
UserModal.MyUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
 return user != null ? UserModal.MyUser(userId: user.uid):null;
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the Solution Worked for me. So what I did was :

**Before:**

```
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(User user){
    return user != null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
   }
```

Class file :

```
  class User {
  final String uid;
  User({required this.uid});
}
```

**After:**
I changed Class name from **User** to **MyUser** and the changed to code like this to make it work.

```
   User _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return MyUser(uid: user!.uid);
  }
```

Class file:

```
  class MyUser {
  final String uid;
  MyUser({required this.uid});
}
```

This is not the authentic solution, but something is better than nothing. :-)